# Easy way to tell what has field history tracking enabled

Tags: history-tracking, field-history

I am looking for an easy way to verify what all has field history tracking enabled(and their retention policies).  I was able to find this SOQL query

```
SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'account' AND IsFieldHistoryTracked = true
```

It does a great job, however it just lists fields for a single object, and doesn't include the actual retention policies.  I have seen the below guides floating around, however I have not been able to successfully extract the information I need:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_history_retention.meta/field_history_retention/meta_historyretentionpolicy.htm

http://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_history_retention.meta/field_history_retention/field_audit_trail.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315117&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Does anyone have an apex execution, or easier way, to get the retention policies for each object, and what fields are marked?  Any information would be greatly appreciated.